# Table only displays 1 row when debugger says there should be 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making an web app which should allow you to create new items inline (without saving it just yet).
Anyway, adding the first row is no problem and displays just fine.
Then when i add a second or even third it will only show the last row i added.
I've tried googling it, but to no avail.

The asp.net Page:

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="tbAdress"><%:accContacts %>:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <asp:Table ID="tblContactsOverview" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped">
                        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                            <asp:TableHeaderCell><%:conFirstName %></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                            <asp:TableHeaderCell><%:conLastName %></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                            <asp:TableHeaderCell>E-mail</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                            <asp:TableHeaderCell><%:contactsTelnr %></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                            <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="AddContactHead" runat="server"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addContact"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    </asp:Table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

c# code:

```
        private void contactsRows(string c1, string c2,string c3, string c4)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = c1;
        cell2.Text = c2;
        cell3.Text = c3;
        cell4.Text = c4;
        cell5.Text = "<span class=\"label label-success\">NEW</span>";
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        row.Cells.Add(cell3);
        row.Cells.Add(cell4);
        row.Cells.Add(cell5);
        //todo prevent reset
        tblContactsOverview.Rows.Add(row);
        tbConEmail.Value = string.Empty;
        tbConFirstname.Value = string.Empty;
        tbConLastname.Value = string.Empty;
        tbConPhone.Value = string.Empty;
    }
```

side note: I've included Jquery in the project, altough i don't think it should impact this table.

Comment: have you checked tblContactsOverview is reset on every add row oration?

Comment: Why you are using TableHeaderRow? Try TableRow instead

Comment: @DhavalPatel, it isn't, the row count displays the expected amount of rows in debug mode.

Comment: @demonplus because it's the header of the table, the rows are added by c#, or am i missing something?

Comment: Your whole page gets recreated each time you click the button, so unless you're persisting the added rows so that the server can include them on each page load, they'll be gone. This seems like something that should be done with JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Could you please show how you call contactsRows?